# Pulling last names but not sorting them alphabetically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to sort an array of mine by the last name alphabetically for a while but can't figure it out, I've tried all the different sorting combos that I can think of, I am not sure where I'm going wrong but this is what ive tried so far:

```
 function sortAccountsByLastName(accounts) {
return accounts.sort((x, y)=> x.last - y.last)
}
```

This is the prompt I'm given:

The `sortAccountsByLastName()` function has a single parameter:

- An array of accounts.

It returns a sorted array of objects. The objects are sorted alphabetically by last name.

This is just some of the data I have to work with:

```
const accounts = [
{
id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
age: 25,
name: {
  first: "Esther",
  last: "Tucker",
},
company: "ZILLACON",
email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM",
},
{
id: "5f446f2ed46724f41c9fc431",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
age: 35,
name: {
  first: "Ferrell",
  last: "Morris",
},
company: "ECOLIGHT",
email: "ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
registered: "Thursday, February 8, 2018 1:16 PM",
},
{
id: "5f446f2e5e2952040e9f9b88",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/robertson.simmons@goko.tv",
age: 38,
name: {
  first: "Robertson",
  last: "Simmons",
},
company: "GOKO",
email: "robertson.simmons@goko.tv",
registered: "Monday, October 30, 2017 10:28 PM",
},
{
id: "5f446f2e637138095dcc3db2",
picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/allen.bartlett@poshome.co.uk",
age: 30,
name: {
  first: "Allen",
  last: "Bartlett",
},
company: "POSHOME",
email: "allen.bartlett@poshome.co.uk",
registered: "Saturday, June 6, 2015 1:07 PM",
}
```

I've attempted to simplify my code above but still have not found success in correcting it, It is returning the last names but it is not sorting them alphabetically. Any feedback would be useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Your `last` property is nested in the `name` object, so it should be `x.name.last`. Also, see: [String#localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). `accounts.sort((x, y)=> x.name.last.localeCompare(y.name.last));`

Comment: Dang, i tried that but wrote a little differently, thank you @pilchard

Comment: No worries, glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @pilchard who was able to fix my code to get it running properly the correct code is:

```
function sortAccountsByLastName(accounts) {
return accounts.sort((x, y)=> x.name.last.localeCompare(y.name.last));
}
```